# getCheckedRadioButtonId() returning useless int?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

I have a button's onClickListener that needs to detect which radiobutton was selected when the user clicks the button. Currently, the Log.v you see below in the onClickListener is not returning a useless bit of info:

This is clicking submit three times with a different radio selected each time:

> 04-27 19:24:42.417: V/submit(1564): 1094168584
>
> 04-27 19:24:45.048: V/submit(1564): 1094167752
>
> 04-27 19:24:47.348: V/submit(1564): 1094211304

So, I need to know which radioButton is actually selected - is there a way to get the object of the radiobutton? I want to be able to get it's id# from XML, as well as its current text.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public void buildQuestions(JSONObject question) throws JSONException {

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) questionBox.findViewById(R.id.responseRadioGroup);

    Button chartsButton = (Button) questionBox.findViewById(R.id.chartsButton);
    chartsButton.setTag(question);
    Button submitButton = (Button) questionBox.findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

    chartsButton.setOnClickListener(chartsListener);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(submitListener);

    TagObj tagObj = new TagObj(question, radioGroup);
    submitButton.setTag(tagObj);

}

public OnClickListener submitListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if (userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(activity)) {
            TagObj tagObject = (TagObj) v.getTag();
            RadioGroup radioGroup = tagObject.getRadioGroup();
            JSONObject question = tagObject.getQuestion();

            Log.v("submit", Integer.toString(radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
            SubmitTask submitTask = new SubmitTask((Polling) activity, question);
            submitTask.execute();

        }
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns the `id` of the `RadioButton`(or `-1` if no `RadioButtons` are checked) that is checked in the `Radiogroup`. If you set distinct ids to the `RadioButons` in the layout then you will try to match those ids with the return of the method to see which one is checked:

```
//field in the class
private static final int RB1_ID = 1000;//first radio button id
private static final int RB2_ID = 1001;//second radio button id
private static final int RB3_ID = 1002;//third radio button id

//create the RadioButton
RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton(this);
//set an id
rb1.setId(RB1_ID);


    int btn = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    switch (btn) {
    case RB1_ID:
        // the first RadioButton is checked.
    break;
        //other checks for the other RadioButtons ids from the RadioGroup
    case -1:
        // no RadioButton is checked inthe Radiogroup
    break;
    }
```

Comment: My radio buttons are programmatic - they don't have XML counter parts. Is there a way to do this still?

Comment: @Davek804 Of course. When you create the `RadioButtons` set them distinct ids with `setId()`. Then in the switch statement from my answer use the numbers you assign as ids instead of `R.id.radio_button1`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Excellent, all set up! Thanks.

Comment: What if I have an ArrayList of RadioButtons? I see an .add() and a .set() for the Array, but do not see a set ID method.

Comment: @tccpg288 An ArrayList is just a container for those buttons. You'll need to iterate over the ArrayList, get each RadioButton and then set a(unique) id on it using setId().

Comment: @Luksprog figured it out, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

store the checked ID, then compare it to each button using the function radioButton.getID() using a switch statement or if-else chains

Answer (score 1):

I am setting initial checked radioButton in `RadioGroup` xml

```
 <RadioGroup
          android:id="@+id/rgCustomized"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:checkedButton="@+id/rbNotCustomized"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

          <RadioButton
              android:id="@+id/rbCustomized"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
              android:text="@string/yes" />

          <RadioButton
              android:id="@+id/rbNotCustomized"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/no" />

 </RadioGroup>
```

And I identify which radioButton is selected like this

```
rgCustomized.checkedRadioButtonId==rbCustomized.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think relying on what `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns is not good practice if you want to store it into the database or to use it.

**Because:**

- `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` value will keep changing for each `RadioButton` and if there are two similar values (two views in the same hierarchy) Android will choose the first one. Unless you provided a unique Ids with method `generateViewId()` and set it to the view with `setId()`.
- `getCheckedRadioButtonId()` will return unknown value.

**Therefore**

Switching on `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` and implement your custom values to each selection then use that custom value, not the View Id.

### Example to use values from selected Radio Button:

```
int selected = -1;
switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.one_radioButton:
        selected = 0;
        break;
    case R.id.two_radioButton:
        selected = 1;
        break;
    case R.id.three_radioButton:
        selected = 2;
        break;
}
    // return a custom value you specific
    Log.d(TAG, "selectedBox: " + selectedBox);   

    // return a random unknown number value
    Log.d(TAG, "radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(): " + radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
```

### Example to populate selected RadioButton to UI:

```
    switch (selected) {
        case 0:
            oneRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 1:
            twoRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
        case 2:
            threeRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;
    }
```