# A variable holds an unexpected value

Tags: java, android

I'm building a module for checking an answer in my Android java app and it doesn't work. While debugging it shows that the variable holds a value that is completely unexpected for it to hold. Could please someone explain what the problem might be? Here is the module:

```java
private void QuizOperations() {

        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,"quizOperation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        answered = true; // when the question is already answered Set bool to true
        RadioButton rbSelected = findViewById(rbGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        int indexofchild =rbGroup.indexOfChild(rbSelected) +1;
        int answerNr = indexofchild  +1;
        checkSolution(answerNr,rbSelected);// method checks if the answer that is selected by the user corresponds to the answer in the database
    }
```

The intended way was rbselected getting the index of the RadioButton pressed by the user, and than answerNr gets the index of this button as int. Than it passes in to the checksolution() function which checks if the AnswerNr corresponds to the right answer in the database. However, while debugging answerNr holds the value of 5 whichever button I press.

[Debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxD7l.png)

Let me know if any additional code needed. Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question is incomplete add more details like what is the expected value what is UI for this radio group? how many options it has? which one is selected when you get 5? what was your expectation?

Comment: you don't get the value right. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057529/7967235, but don't use `switch`, just use `if - else`

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh the expected value is so the Answer number will hold the value of the button index. For example if the first button is pressed, than the AnswerNr will hold value of 1. It holds this value of 5 whichever button I press. There are 4 options

Comment: As I see there is a problem with the getCheckedButtonId() Function. Does anybody does a wayaround or maybe an alternative module code for getting proper value to answerNr for each pressed button?

Comment: That's good you've noticed the mistake. The way you're detecting button pressed is incorrect. Plus if you need an index from a button, you should `tag`'d the buttons.

Comment: @Darkman can you please elaborate on that? I'm very new to android dev. How do you tag the button and detect the index of a pressed one ?

Comment: is this code inside an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very minimalistic example on how to detect the view is being pressed, set/get id from tag.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#333333">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private String[] answers = {
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
    };
    
    private RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        rb1 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rb2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        rb3 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        
        rb1.setTag("0");
        rb2.setTag("1");
        rb3.setTag("2");
        
        rb1.setOnClickListener(this);
        rb2.setOnClickListener(this);
        rb3.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        final int index = Integer.parseInt((String)view.getTag());
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radioButton1:
                rb2.setChecked(false);
                rb3.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, answers[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                rb1.setChecked(false);
                rb3.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, answers[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
            case R.id.radioButton3:
                rb1.setChecked(false);
                rb2.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, answers[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow man, thank you so much. Just so I fully understand it. Why is it necessary to uncheck all other buttons?

Comment: @YakovMashin Why don't you just test it for yourself. It is not so hard to comment those lines, is it?